# PHP, JAVASCRIPT inside php loop

Tags: javascript, php

I currently working with voting system. Everytime a voter selects a candidate the javascript should work but nothing happens. Here is my code.

```
<?php while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { ?>    
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="row">
            <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-md-push-1" id="labelpad" for="username"><?php echo $row['position']; ?></label>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-push-0"><br>
                    <?php 
                    $stmt1 = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM candidate WHERE position = ?");
                    $stmt1->bindParam(1, $row['position']);
                    $stmt1->execute();
                    while ($row1 = $stmt1->fetch()) 
                    {                   
                    ?>
                    <label>
                        <input id="" class="uniform_on" name="selector[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row1['candidate_id'];?>">
                    </label>
                    <?php echo "<label>".$row1['name']."</label>"; ?><br>
                            <script>        
                                $(".uniform_on").change(function(){
                                var max= <?php $row1['vote_limit'];?>
                                if( $(".uniform_on:checked").length == max {
                                    $(".uniform_on").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                                        alert('5 Items allowed per borrow');

                                    $(".uniform_on:checked").removeAttr('disabled');

                                }else{

                                    $(".uniform_on").removeAttr('disabled');
                                }
                                })
                            </script>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>  
            </div>
```

Comment: You've got at least 3 separate layers to put debug output on, 4 if you want AJAX-type functionality. My suggestion first is put some debug statements around each of the PHP, the JS and the database calls and see where that's executing and where it isn't. Are you familiar with the sort of thing I'm talking about?

Comment: I see the "vote limit" is the main problem. How do you expect to use the vote limit? would it limit the amount of votes per user per checkbox group, or would it limit the amount of votes for the entire poll (even for different positions)?

Comment: Will the candidates only pertain to one position or can there be the same candidates for multiple positions?

Comment: @Bryan Are you there?